# Count numbers by category

Tags: python, printing, numbers, statistics

There are 10 numbers provided.

```
10, 12, 12, 5, 5, 4, 7, 16, 18, 11
```

I want to print

- how many numbers are bigger than 15,
- how many numbers are smaller than 5,
- and other numbers.

for example, there are:

- **2** numbers bigger than 15
- **1** number smaller than 15
- **7** numbers which is between 5 to 15

So I want to get those 2,1,7 by python code

Comment: What do you mean by else numbers?

Comment: This s a VERY simple problem and I would suggest you to look at some basic python tutorials to get this done.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: @ILostMySpoon I tried for an hour...

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehensions:

```
a = len([i for i in your_list if i > 15])
b = len([i for i in your_list if i < 5])
c = len([i for i in your_list if not (i > 15 or i < 5)])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots and lots ways to do this.

One of them using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (I kept it very simple), assuming the number are stored in a list

```
l = [10, 12, 12, 5, 5, 4, 7, 16, 18, 11]
print len([x for x in l if x < 5]), len([x for x in l if x >= 5 and x <= 15]), len([x for x in l if x > 15])
```

Result:

```
1 7 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should study a bit of basic syntax in python.
Use the [list comprehension](http://www.codecademy.com/glossary/python/list-comprehensions).
Python offer you a wonderful method to resolve the problem.